# How to add a custom helper in my module?

Tags: module, magento2, configuration, helper

How to create new Helper or override/rewrite Core Helper in Magento 2 module?

I tried adding dependency into my `module.xml` of Custom Module, but it doesn't load Helper class at all.

Below is my `module.xml`;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Company1_Module1" schema_version="1.0.0" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>Magento_Directory</sequence>
  </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 21):

Create: `app/code/Company1/Module1/composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "company1/module-module1",
    "description": "",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-directory": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Company1\\Module1\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Create: `app/code/Company1/Module1/registration.php`

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company1_Module1',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create: `app/code/Company1/Module1/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company1_Module1" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Directory"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Module creation done. So now create helper class inside **Helper** folder.

`app/code/Company1/Module1/Helper/Data.php`:

```
namespace Company1\Module1\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function someMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**How to use helper class inside controller**

```
$this->_objectManager->create('Company1\Module1\Helper\Data')->someMethod();
```

**How to use helper class inside block**

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Company1\Module1\Helper\Data $helper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

So `$this->helper` is now instance of Data.

For overwrite any class you can use **preference**.

`app/code/Company1/Module1/etc/di.xml`:

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Helper\Data" type="Company1\Module1\Helper\Data" />
</config>
```

You can also use plugin. Plugin is the best way to overcome rewrite conflict.
for more information [plugin example](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: Hi Sohel, Hi Fayyaz, How to instantiate an helper class from my custom module in a test program in the directory at the same level as the root of Magento? Could you please answer my post on SO here, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360584/how-to-instantiate-an-helper-class-from-my-custom-module-in-a-test-program-in-th