# How to get next and previous product on detail page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, product, category, catalog

I am new to Magento 2 and I can not find `view.phtml` file in Catalog. I want to show previous and next product from the category of the current product in Product detail Page, do any on know how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case, you should **create a custom module which have helper  class**.

- [Instantiating Helpers in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10517/instantiating-helpers-in-magento-2)
- [Custom helper in custom module in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92078/custom-helper-in-custom-module-in-magento-2)

At this *helper class,create two functions*  `getPreviousProduct()` and `getNextProduct()` which give us previous and next product link receptively .

### Helper class:

```
<?php
namespace Company1\Module1\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;   
    protected $productRepository; 
     public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository

         )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
  public function getNextProduct()
    {
        $prodId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product')->getId();

        $catArray = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');

        if($catArray){
            $catArray = $catArray->getProductsPosition();
            $keys = array_flip(array_keys($catArray));
            $values = array_keys($catArray);

            $productId = $values[$keys[$prodId]-1];

            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            if($product->getId()){
               return $product->getProductUrl();
            }
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public function getPreviousProduct()
    {
        $prodId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product')->getId();

        $catArray = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');

        if($catArray){
            $catArray = $catArray->getProductsPosition();
            $keys = array_flip(array_keys($catArray));
            $values = array_keys($catArray);

            $productId = $values[$keys[$prodId]-1];

            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            if($product->getId()){
               return $product->getProductUrl();
            }
            return false;
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

Then you need call this helper class review summary phtml file  `app/design/frontend/Vendor/template/Magento_Catalog/tamplates/product/view/review.phtml`

**call add this code**

```
<a href="<?php $this->helper('Company1\Module1\Helper\Data')->getPreviousProduct() ?>">Previouse</a>

<a href="<?php $this->helper('Company1\Module1\Helper\Data')->getNextProduct() ?>">Next</a>
```

***Note: Code is not tested, is created basic of idea***

Comment: $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
 will not work once we are into detail page from search results

Answer (score 2):

I have created an extension to have that feature. You can refer my extension:
https://github.com/davidduong90/Next-previous-product

I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!