# How to redirect on specific product page in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, frontend

I want to redirect on specific product page when i click on detail view link.

For ex. :- In grid , I click on first product detail. After I want to redirect on that specific product view page.

How to do it..?

In this image d1 is product sku . I want to do it when I clicked on view then it will redirect on d1 product view page .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***May be you want product Url by using sku***

- First you should create a custom   helper
  [Custom helper in custom module in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92078/custom-helper-in-custom-module-in-magento-2)
- Then from that class you should  get product url by sku

==================

```
<?php
namespace Company1\Module1\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_productRepository;
    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context$context
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    )
    {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    } 
    public function getProductBySku($sku)
    {
        $_product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
        if(!$_product){
            return false;
        }
        return $_product->getProductUrl();

    }   

}
```

Then add  at phtml

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Company1\Module1\Helper\Data');
$producturl = $_helper->getProductBySku([sku]);
```

at view for getting product URL

Comment: when i don't set value of sku.. still product redirect on product view page.. how is it possible?