# How to include a non-Magento 2 PHP file in an Observer?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2.4

How do we include_once an external (outside of Magento 2 code but on the same web server) PHP file?

I added the events.xml and adminuserlogin.php files below, into an already activated and fucntioning admin module, but my attempts to have the Observer call/include the PHP file does nothing.  Do you see anything wrong with the code?

The module folder structures and the code are as follows:

**/home/abc/public_html/app/code/abcCo/Backend/etc/adminhtml/events.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="backend_auth_user_login_success">
            <observer name="backend_activity" instance="abcCo\Backend\Observer\adminuserlogin" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

**/home/abc/public_html/app/code/abcCo/Backend/Observer/adminuserlogin.php:**

```
<?php

namespace abcCo\Backend\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class adminuserlogin implements ObserverInterface
{
   public function __construct() 
{ 
    //Observer initialization code...
    //You can use dependency injection to get any class this observer may need.
    }

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       // execute an external php script when I log in.

include_once '/home/abc/public_html/app/code/abcCo/testModule/Controller/Index/login_test.php';

    } 
} 

?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your file on the ro

Add ./ on your path.

Example:

```
include_once("./app/code/abcCo/testModule/Controller/Index/login_test.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested

```
<?php

namespace abcCo\Backend\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
//location is determined whether you use <working_root>/index.php or <working_root>/pub/index.php if pub/index.php you'll want to use  ../app/code/... in require_once funct.
require_once(__DIR__ .'app/code/abcCo/testModule/Controller/Index/login_test.php');
class adminuserlogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct() 
    { 
     //Observer initialization code...
     //You can use dependency injection to get any class this observer may need.
    }

     public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     // use login_test.php functions here. 
    } 
} 

?>
```

Now that being said, you probably should just create a helper class that provides the functionality in the included file.

Here's something for reference: [Custom helper in custom module in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92078/custom-helper-in-custom-module-in-magento-2) about helper classes.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  The added code did not work, even with some variations that I made to it.  I'll give the custom helper a look as you suggested.

Comment: Yeah thats a better direction, I hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Zend_Loader;

class GetPdfData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $dir;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->initializePDF();
    }

    /**
     * Construct initialization of mpdf library
     */
    protected function initializePDF()
    {
        error_reporting(0);

        $path = $this->dir->getRoot() . "/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/";

        $this->pdf = $path . 'Mpdf.php';

        //include_once $this->pdf;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pdf, null, true);

        $this->configvariables = $path . 'Config/ConfigVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->configvariables;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->configvariables, null, true);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Your Code";
        exit();
    }
}
```

**Note: Here we need to add absolute path of files which we want to include_once or require_once. MPdf is installing via composer require mpdf/mpdf command and this module placed into the vendor directory.**