# Magento 2.4.4: How to get Gift Message from Order object in my Observer class subscribed to checkout_onepage_controller_success_action?

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, event-observer, giftmessage

With upgrade to Magento 2.4.4, I'm using `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` to get order information that I insert into a custom table that I created in Magento. We're allowing customers to enter gift message only in the cart page which means it is allowed at order level but not at the item level.

What is the method to retrieve the Gift message entered in the cart page from the order object that we get in the Observer class subscribed to `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`.

Below is my old code:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Perfectmakeupmirrors\Order\Observer;

use \Perfectmakeupmirrors\Order\Helper\Data;
use \Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class OrderSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $logger;
    protected $helper;
    protected $order_gift_repository;

    /**
     * @desc Construct method which is used to inject dependency of helper class
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Perfectmakeupmirrors\Order\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param \Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $order_gift_repository
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, Data $helper, OrderRepositoryInterface $order_gift_repository){
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->helper  = $helper;
        $this->order_gift_repository = $order_gift_repository;
    }

    /**
     * @desc Observer execute method which gets control from dispatcher of 'sales_order_save_after' event
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer object
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        // 1. Retrieve the Gift Message using dependency injection from the order object.
        // 2. Fetch the record from poms_jobs_queue along with the record ID where the status = "-1".
        // This order object is obtained only after the event "sales_order_save_after" is dispatched.
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        // Retrieving the Gift Message using dependency injection OrderRepositoryInterface
        // Ensure to use getId() to get the real order ID.
        // Call getMessage() to get the gift message.
        // Exception handling deployed here to address the issue with the empty gift message.
        // Order with empty gift message raises NoSuchEntityException exception.
        // Exception handling is how this situation is dealt with in Magento 2.
        $gift_message = '';         // Initialize to blank.
        try {
            // Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $order_gift_repository
            $gift_object  = $this->order_gift_repository->get($order->getId());
            // This line is what throws an exception in case of an empty gift message.
            $gift_message = $gift_object->getMessage();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            // Valid scenario of No gift message specified. Nothing to be done.
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Error scenario. Since empty gift message throws this error, logging commented
            // $this->logger->debug("Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
        }

        // Call the helper class method to update the order_info array.
        // Pass order object and the gift message as arguments.
        try {
            $this->helper->add_gift_message_to_order_info($order, $gift_message);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->debug("***ERROR*** Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: upload your code here which you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Gift message on event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`, do the following steps:

1. Make sure your module load after Magento_Checkout module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

2. Create the events.xml file:
   `<your module dir>/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="add_gift_message_to_order_info" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\AddGiftMessageToOrderInfo" />
    </event>
    </event>
</config>
```

3. Create the Observer file: `<your module dir>/Observer/AddGiftMessageToOrderInfo.php`

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddGiftMessageToOrderInfo implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $giftMessageOrderRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $giftMessageOrderRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $giftMessageOrderRepository
    ) {
        $this->giftMessageOrderRepository = $giftMessageOrderRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Add Gift message to order information on checkout success pages
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $giftMessage = $this->giftMessageOrderRepository->get($order->getId());
        $message = $giftMessage->getMessage();
        // Your custom code goes here
    }
}
```

Compare to your Observer, your code should be working as expected.

Comment: Made necessary changes and I'm able to get gift message. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers!